# Ajax отправка файлов в письме

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Почему-то не приходят вложения в письмах - сами письма приходят, а вложений нет.

Вот разметка и скрипты

```
  $('#proj_form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formValid = true;
    $('#proj_form input,textarea').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('id') == 'text-captcha') { return true; }
      var formGroup = $(this).parents('.form-group');
      var glyphicon = formGroup.find('.form-control-feedback');
      if (this.checkValidity()) {
        formGroup.addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-error');
        glyphicon.addClass('glyphicon-ok').removeClass('glyphicon-remove');
      } else {
        formGroup.addClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
        glyphicon.addClass('glyphicon-remove').removeClass('glyphicon-ok');
        formValid = false;  
      }
    });

      var name = $("#proj_name").val();
      var phone = $("#proj_phone").val();
      var time = $("#proj_time").val();
      var message = $("#proj_message").val();
      var captcha = $("#proj-captcha").val();
  var file_data = $('#proj_image').prop('files')[0];  
  var form_data = new FormData();                  
  form_data.append('file', file_data);
  form_data.append('name', name);
  form_data.append('email', email);
  form_data.append('message', message);
  form_data.append('captcha', captcha);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "feedback/send_proj.php",
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
        success : function(text){
          if (text == "success"){
            $('#proj_form').hide();
            $('#msgSubmit_proj').removeClass('hidden');
          }
          if (text == "invalidcaptcha") {
            inputCaptcha = $("#text-captcha");
            formGroupCaptcha = inputCaptcha.parents('.form-group');
            glyphiconCaptcha = formGroupCaptcha.find('.form-control-feedback');
            formGroupCaptcha.addClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
            glyphiconCaptcha.addClass('glyphicon-remove').removeClass('glyphicon-ok');
            $('#img-captcha').attr('src', 'feedback/captcha.php?id='+Math.random()+'');
            $("#text-captcha").val('');
          }
        }
      }); 
  });
```

Форма

```
<form id="proj_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">Имя*</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="proj_name" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
    <label for="phone" class="control-label">Телефон*</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="proj_phone" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
    <label for="time" class="control-label">Время звонка</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="proj_time"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
    <label for="email" class="control-label">Сообщение</label>
      <textarea id="proj_message" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
    <label for="email" class="control-label">Прикрепите файлы проекта</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" id="proj_image" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success send_but">Отправить</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Скрипт обработчика

```
<?php
session_start();
$name = $_POST["proj_name"];
$phone = $_POST["proj_phone"];
$time = $_POST["proj_time"];
$message = $_POST["proj_message"];

  $emailTo = "email@email.ru";
  $subject = "Тема письма";
  $body = "--------------------------------------\n";
  $body .= date("Y.m.d H:i")."\n";
  $body .= "Содержимое заполненных пользователем полей:\n";
  $body .= "Имя: ".$name."\n";
  $body .= "Телефон: ".$phone."\n";
  $body .= "Время звонка: ".$time."\n";
  $body .= "Сообщение: \n".$message."\n";
  $body .= "Сообщение: \n".$file."\n";
$sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '';
}
else {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
}
  $success = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, "From: noreply@email.ru \r\n");
  if ($success) {
    echo "success";
  }
  else {
    echo "invalid";
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Оставляю решение, мало ли кому-то пригодится.

```
require dirname(__FILE__).'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->From      = 'noreply@site.ru';
  $mail->FromName  = 'Имя сайта';
  $mail->Subject   = 'Тема письма';
  $mail->Body      = $body;
  $mail->AddAddress('email@site.ru');

  if ( $_FILES['file']['error']==0 ) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'files/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
    $mail->addAttachment('files/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
  }
  $success = $mail->Send();
```